# filter a array from values stored in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array

```
sourceArray = [{'type':'A'}, {'type':'B'}, {'type':'C'}, {'type':'D'}];
arrayB  = ['B', 'C'];
```

I want to filter array `sourceArray` from values which `arrayB` contains.
We can do this by iterating `arrayB`, but just want some good way to do this.

```
filteredArray = [];
for(x in arrayB)
{
filteredArray.concat( sourceArray.filter(function(e1){ return e1.type == arrayB[x])} );
}
```

can be have any way to do this more gracefully.

Comment: Does arrayB contain just a handful of elements or more ?

Comment: it will contain 5-10 elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just `.filter` it:

```js
sourceArray = [{'type':'A'}, {'type':'B'}, {'type':'C'}, {'type':'D'}];
arrayB  = ['B', 'C'];

result = sourceArray.filter(function(item) {
  return arrayB.indexOf(item.type) >= 0;
});

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(result,0,3));
```

[`[].filter(func)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) iterates an array and collects elements for which `func` returns `true`. In our function, we check whether `arrayB` contains `item.type` and return true if it does (see [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)).

ES6 solution, for those who already use it:

```
sourceArray = [{'type':'A'}, {'type':'B'}, {'type':'C'}, {'type':'D'}];
arrayB  = ['B', 'C'];

setB = new Set(arrayB)
result = sourceArray.filter(item => setB.has(item.type))
```

Comment: thanks it's worked. can you elaborate please how it does.

Comment: @Ankuli: added an explanation

Answer (score 3):

There's the solution of [filtering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and using `indexOf`, but it contains a hidden iteration which is costly if your `arrayB` array contains more than just a few elements.

In the general case, the efficient solution is to build a hash map of the elements so that the filtering operation is faster. This can be done like this:

```
var filteredArray = sourceArray.filter(
    function(v){ return this[v.type] }.bind(arrayB.reduce(
        function(s,v){ s[v]=1; return s }, Object.create(null)
    ))
)
```

In this code `arrayB.reduce(function(s,v){ s[v]=1; return s }, {}))` is an object whose keys are the valid types :  `{B: 1, C: 1}`. JavaScript engines are very fast at repetitively retrieving the properties of such an object.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var sourceArray = [{
    'type': 'A'
}, {
    'type': 'B'
}, {
    'type': 'C'
}, {
    'type': 'D'
}];
var arrayB = ['B', 'C'];

var desiredArr = sourceArray.filter(function (val) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= arrayB.length; ++i) {
        if (val.type == arrayB[i]){
            return val;
        }
    }
});
alert(JSON.stringify(desiredArr));
```

Comment: `return val` is in `if` bock